# What is the complex Fourier transform of a winding number?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, curves, winding-number

My question regards complex and Fourier analysis.
If the winding number of a closed curve $\gamma$ in the complex plane with respect to $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ is given as follows:
$$\text{ind}_\gamma(z_0) := \frac 1{2\pi\mathrm i} \int_\gamma \frac{\mathrm d\zeta}{\zeta - z_0}.$$

**What is it's complex Fourier transform?**
I tried to evaluate the following, but don't really know what to do apart from swapping some factors in and out:

$$\widehat{\text{ind}}_\gamma(\omega_0)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac 1{2\pi\mathrm i} \int_\gamma \frac{\mathrm d\zeta}{\zeta - \omega_0} e^{-it\omega_0}dt.$$

Here, $\omega_0=\omega_x+i\omega_y$ is a complex number (does that even make sense for a frequency?). I am very thankful for any help on this one.

**Edit:** I came across this problem in an article by Pan et al. called "Sampling Curves with Finite Rate of Innovation". There it occurs in section II. A. in a slightly more general way, with a function in the numerator. I replaced that function by the constant function $1$ and ended up with a winding number.

Comment: Should that be $\zeta - t$ in the denominator?

Comment: Take $U$ a simply connected domain such that $U \cap \Bbb{R} = \bigcup_{j=1}^J[a_j,b_j]$ and $\gamma = \partial U$ then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty ind_\gamma(t) e^{-i t u} dt = \sum_{j=1}^J \int_{a_j}^{b_j} e^{-itu}dt $, then extend to arbitrary rectifiable closed curves crossing the real axis finitely many times.

Comment: Where does this problem come from ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. The question seems very interesting: however, in order for it to be a very [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), it would be better to provide some context, i.e. explaining why is it important for you, as also @Héhéhé pointed out.

Comment: How did you arrive at the idea that the quantity computed in the paper is a winding number (or even integer-valued)? Note also that the Fourier integral is over 2 real dimensions $x,y$, with factor $e^{i(xω_x+yω_y)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer LutzL! As I said, I arrived at a winding number after replacing the numerator function with the constant function 1. In that case it should be integer-valued if I am not missing something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paper, a function with 2 real variables is defined
$$
I(x,y)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{F(u,v)}{u+iv-(x+iy)}d(u+iv).
$$
Of this function, the Fourier transform in both variables is considered, it is assumed that the integration over the (compact) curve $C$ can be moved out of the Fourier integration
\begin{align}
\hat I(ω_x,ω_y)&=A_{Fourier}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{F(u,v)}{u+iv-(x+iy)}\,d(u+iv)\,e^{-i(xω_x+yω_y)}\,d(x,y)
\\
&=\frac{A_{Fourier}}{2\pi i}\int_CF(u,v)\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{e^{-i(xω_x+yω_y)}}{u+iv-(x+iy)}\,d(x,y)\,d(u+iv)
\\
&=\frac{A_{Fourier}}{2\pi i}\int_CF(u,v)e^{-i(uω_x+vω_y)}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{e^{i((u-x)ω_x+(v-y)ω_y)}}{(u-x)+i(v-y)}\,d(x,y)\,d(u+iv)
\\
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_CF(u,v)e^{-i(uω_x+vω_y)}\,d(u+iv)\cdot{A_{Fourier}}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{e^{i(xω_x+yω_y)}}{x+iy}\,d(x,y)
\end{align}
For the last factor one now finds
\begin{align}
A_{Fourier}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{e^{i(xω_x+yω_y)}}{x+iy}\,d(x,y)
&={A_{Fourier}}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{e^{i(xω_x+yω_y)}(ω_x-iω_y)}{(xω_x+yω_y)+i(yω_x-xω_y)}\,d(x,y)
\\
&=A_{Fourier}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{e^{i(xω_x+yω_y)}}{(xω_x+yω_y)+i(yω_x-xω_y)}\,\frac{d(xω_x+yω_y,yω_x-xω_y)}{ω_x+iω_y}
\\
&=\frac{A_{Fourier}}{ω_x+iω_y}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{e^{ix}}{x+iy}\,d(x,y)
=\frac{A_{Fourier}}{ω_x+iω_y}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{ix\sin(x)-iy\cos(x)}{x^2+y^2}\,d(x,y)
\end{align}
and somehow the last singular integral can be assigned a finite value.